# Amazon search widget 2.0, how can i pull in a keyword from a querystring via "q="?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, query-string

Sorry to be a pain but i seem to be stuck and cant find any help anywhere on my issue.

I currently have a search box and upon submit of a keyword/phrase (in my example i will say CARS) the query string becomes EXAMPLE.COM/?q=cars

This then fires the page of:  EXAMPLE.COM/SHOPPING.PHP?q=cars

I am implementing the Amazon search widget 2.0 into my shopping page and although you can specify a default search term, Could anyone please advise how i can get this widget to automatically pull in my query string query?

I have tried inserting:  < ?php echo $_GET["q"]; ? >   into the box of where Amazon ask for a default search term but it just doesn't know what i mean when doing this..

Thank you in advance for taking the time to read & possibly reply!

Richard

Answer (score 0):

The Amazon Search 2.0 widget uses JavaScript to pull your saved information from Amazon's servers. That means the information you put into the format box is saved in their databases. You can't use a PHP variable in there. You're better off creating your own search box, and setting the action of the form to search through Amazon. Check out [this link](http://winkpress.com/amazon/add-amazon-search-box-to-wordpress-using-html/) to see what I mean. It's for a WordPress website, but you can implement it into any website.

Comment: That's a great example and i will be able to use that on some other projects without a doubt thank you.. The only issue with it for this project is i need the product results to show on my own webpage damn it.. I wonder if i could find the java code from amazon and try to rip it and host the java on my server and make a few changes to it?

Comment: You could use curl(), pull in the results, and display them on your own page. Then you can stylize the information however you want, and the searcher never leaves your website.

Comment: Yeah that would work, i just don't have any idea where to start with curl() damn it! Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 0):

This should definitely work with the "Search" widget 2.0.  You need to make sure that you have specified the default search value you want in the amzn_assoc_default_search_key property of the widget.

Check your rendered page source for this and make sure the get parameter is in there.  If it is and the widget is ignoring the results maybe its to do with encoding.   Check that you url encode parameters over the url and that you url decode them before putting them into the amzn_assoc_default_search_key value.

Incidentally, I made a function to [streamline adding amazon search widgets into your site](http://www.adam-makes-websites.com/discoveries/making_the_embedding_of_an_amazon_referrals_sales_widget_easier_and_more_intelligent) which you may want to check out.